# string.format on url in vb.net

Tags: .net, vb.net, url, string.format

I am trying to use string.format on a url to pass several values into the string.  It's probably a simple error but I cannot get the following code to work.  It doesn't even build the string.  Any ideas?

Thanks!

```
Public Sub getStockData()
    Dim client As New WebClient()
    Dim url As String
    Dim ticker As String = "MSFT"
    Dim lastPrice As String = "l1"
    Dim volume As String = "v0"
    Dim marketCap As String = "j1"
    Dim divYield As String = "x"
    Dim peRatio As String = "r"
    Dim eps As String = "e"

    url = String.Format("http://finance.yahoo.com/d/quotes.csv?s={0}&f={1}{2}{3}{4}{5}{6}", ticker, lastPrice, marketCap, divYield, peRatio, eps)
    Dim results As String = client.DownloadString(url)
    messagebox.show(results)
End Sub
```

Comment: Do you get an error message? What makes you think it "doesn't biuld the string"?

Comment: I set a breakpoint and url isn't set to anything.

Comment: I see seven params (from 0 to 6) and only six passed on `String.Format`...

Comment: You're right.  Silly mistake.  Marco, if you post that as an answer I will mark it as the accepted answer.

Comment: While I was writing my comment, @jglouie posted his answer telling my same thing. So thank you so much, but my answer wouldn't add anything to this post: accept his answer, it's the one for you :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have 7 values you want to insert (format items {0} thru {6}) but only supply six of them:

```
url = String.Format(
    "http://finance.yahoo.com/d/quotes.csv?s={0}&f={1}{2}{3}{4}{5}{6}", 
    ticker, lastPrice, marketCap, divYield, peRatio, eps)
```

the variable named "volume" is not being used ...

EDIT: Using the official MS term "format items" as pointed out by @SpectralGhost!

Comment: I was gonna say this, but got stuck on the proper name for {x}'s. Microsoft's documentation refers to them as format items.  :P